# GitPython list all files affected by a certain commit

Tags: python, gitpython

I am using this for loop to loop through all commits:

```
repo = Repo("C:/Users/shiro/Desktop/lucene-solr/")
for commit in list(repo.iter_commits()):
    print commit.files_list  # how to do that ?
```

How can I get a list with the files affected from this specific commit ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try it

```
for commit in list(repo.iter_commits()):
    commit.stats.files
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this method is *very* slow. It runs `git diff --numstat`, which calculates a lot more than just the file list.

Comment: FWIW: that that does strange things with renames/moves.

Answer (score 1):

```
from git import Repo
repo = Repo('/home/worldmind/test.git/')
prev = repo.commit('30c55d43d143189698bebb759143ed72e766aaa9')
curr = repo.commit('5f5eb0a3446628ef0872170bd989f4e2fa760277')
diff_index = prev.diff(curr)
for diff in diff_index:
    print(diff.change_type)
    print(f"{diff.a_path} -> {diff.b_path}")
```

Comment: Things get more complicated when `curr` has more than one parent. Dealing with that will likely involve something like `for prev in curr.parents:`  but exactly what to do from there is a function of what you are trying to do.

Comment: There is also the question of what to do when `curr` is an initial commit and doesn't have a parent.

Comment: After some more tinkering, it looks like `commit.diff(None)` is useful (e.g. with initial commits?) in some cases. But I haven't yet played around with it enough to know the details.

Answer (score 0):

`commit.stats.files` works, but it's very slow. It will take several seconds to process a large commit.

This is much faster:

```py
repo = Repo("C:/Users/shiro/Desktop/lucene-solr/")
for commit in list(repo.iter_commits()):
   print(self.repo.git.show(commit.hexsha, name_only=True).split('\n'))
```

Comment: That works but also generates some "human readable" lines that will need to be filtered.

Answer (score -5):

I solved this problem for SCM Workbench. The important file is:

https://github.com/barry-scott/scm-workbench/blob/master/Source/Git/wb_git_project.py

Look at cmdCommitLogForFile() and its helper __addCommitChangeInformation().

The trick is to diff the tree objects.

Comment: StackOverflow highly discourages people from putting answers in linked pages.   Linked pages often get moved or removed, then the answer is gone.

Comment: Can you please update your answer. I'm searching for the same and don't want to search this big file when you already have found the solution there. I want to get all files that are committed currently not all commits since the start of the repo.